# Idiomatic stateful loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there an idiomatic way to express following code in Haskell?

```
main :: IO ()
main = loop initState1 initState2 initState3

loop :: State1 -> State2 -> State3 -> IO ()
loop s1 s2 s3 = do
  s1' <- runService1 s1
  s2' <- runService2 s2
  s3' <- runService3 s3
  loop s1' s2' s3'
```

This code is very verbose so I probably doing something weird.

Comment: Looking at the other answers, I think the code in the question is what I would rather read. It’s basically obvious what this does and you won’t need to change much if you suddenly realise that `runService2` needs to depend on `s1'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
main = fix (zipWithM ($) >=>)
  [runService1, runService2, runService3]
  [initState1 , initState2 , initState3 ]
```

Compare `fix . (>>=) :: IO a -> IO b`, which is `forever`.

Edit: This only works if `State1` = `State2` = `State3`. If not, `data-fix` allows:

```
main = fix (traverse unFix >=>)
  [ana runService1 initState1, ana runService2 initState2, ana runService3 initState3]
```

Answer (score 6):

I practice, you probably want to shove that state in a suitable *state monad*. The `lens` library makes it easy to access that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell    #-}
import Control.Lens.TH
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

data AllState = AllState { _s₀ :: State0, _s₁ :: State1, _s₂ :: State2 }
makeLenses ''AllState

loop :: StateT AllState IO ()
loop = do
   s₀ <~ runService0 <$> use s₀
   s₁ <~ runService1 <$> use s₁
   s₂ <~ runService2 <$> use s₂
   loop

main = evalStateT loop $ AllState initState0 initState1 initState2
```

As such, this doesn't buy you very much over your original code, but it becomes much more convenient if you also give the `runService` actions a suitable state-monad type:

```
runService0 :: StateT State0 IO ()
runService1 :: StateT State1 IO ()
runService2 :: StateT State2 IO ()
```

...then you can simply use the [`zoom`](http://ekmett.github.io/lens/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#t:Zoom) mechanism:

```
loop :: StateT AllState IO ()
loop = do
   zoom s₀ runService0
   zoom s₁ runService1
   zoom s₂ runService2
   loop
```

or as Gurkenglas suggests

```
loop = forever $ do
   zoom s₀ runService0
   zoom s₁ runService1
   zoom s₂ runService2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this should be the answer too.

Comment: You can replace the explicit recursion in the last `loop` with a `forever` in front of the `do`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not more succinct, but solves an infelicity of the original formulation: the "unfolding" of each process is commingled with the "zipping together" of all processes. It would be nice if we could define each process independently, and combine them later as we saw fit.

We need the following auxiliary type:

```
newtype Iter = Iter (IO Iter)

unfoldIter :: (s -> IO s) -> s -> Iter
unfoldIter f s = Iter (unfoldIter f <$> f s)

runIter :: Iter -> IO ()
runIter (Iter action) = action >>= runIter

doNothingIter :: Iter
doNothingIter = unfoldIter return ()

zipIter :: Iter -> Iter -> Iter
zipIter (Iter action1) (Iter action2) =
    Iter (zipIter <$> action1 <*> action2)

instance Monoid Iter where
    mempty = doNothingIter
    mappend = zipIter
```

Then `loop` becomes:

```
loop :: State1 -> State2 -> State3 -> IO ()
loop s1 s2 s3 = 
    runIter $ unfoldIter runService1 s1
           <> unfoldIter runService2 s2
           <> unfoldIter runService3 s3
```

---

If we don't want to define our own auxiliary type, we could use a streaming library that provided a "zipping" operation, like for example [streaming](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#g:8) does.